# How do I place an identical smooth on each facet of a ggplot2 object?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

Here's an example:

```
eg <- data.frame(x = c(1:50, 50:1),  
                 y = c(1:50, 1:50) + rnorm(100),  
                 g = rep(c("a","b"), each=50))  

qplot(x, y, data = eg) +  
  facet_wrap(~ g) +  
  geom_smooth()
```

I'd like to be able to plot the overall smooth on both facets as well as having the facet-specific smooths.

Edit: here's one way.

```
my.smooth <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = eg)
my.data <- data.frame(x = 1:50)                                           
my.data$y <- predict(my.smooth, newdata = my.data) 

qplot(x, y, data = eg) + 
    facet_wrap(~ g) + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    geom_smooth(data = my.data)
```

Thanks for any help!

Andrew

Comment: The examples here should be relevant: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_smooth.html

Comment: schweet, glad you were able to get it figured out. Feel free to answer your own question and then accept it, perfectly legit thing to do. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 6):

Clever trick: [setting the faceting variable to NULL](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/ggplot2-overplotting-in-a-faceted-scatterplot/)

```
library(ggplot2)
eg <- data.frame(x = c(1:50, 50:1),  
                 y = c(1:50, 1:50) + rnorm(100),  
                 g = rep(c("a","b"), each=50))  

p <- qplot(x, y, data = eg) +  
  facet_wrap(~ g) +  
  geom_smooth()

p + geom_smooth(data=within(eg, g <- NULL), fill="red")
```

Or if you prefer, use `facet_grid(..., margins=TRUE)`:

```
p + facet_grid(.~g, margins=TRUE)
```