# ggplot2: Single smooth line for several line plots within facets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, smoothing, facet-wrap

I want to plot multiple facets with several lines each. In every facet, for the set of line plots, I would like to show a kind of smooth line representing a general trend for all those lines in a given particular facet.
Does anybody know if it is possible? I have tried so far something like this:

`ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) + geom_line('GRAY') + facet_wrap(~ class) + geom_smooth('loess')`
[(see figure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG8Qv.png)

However, what I observe is another line for every line plot within each facet, instead of a single line within every facet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please simulate some data which demonstrates what you have tried and what you're after. That `geom_line()` you are using is probably adding one line. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673074/how-do-i-place-an-identical-smooth-on-each-facet-of-a-ggplot2-object)

Comment: @ValterBeaković I tried what you suggested, with no changes. Instead, I got the same plot with all categories in every facet.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I added the figure it generated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of mydata?

Comment: Check the answer below using the iris dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
... +
geom_smooth(aes(group=class), method="lm") +
...
```

Should make one line pr. facet

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with the iris dataset:

```
    gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + 
            geom_line() + 
            facet_wrap(~ Species) +
            geom_smooth(data = within(iris, Species <- NULL), fill = "red")
    gg
```

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to help OP (he or she should to it him/herself, though), feel free to edit their question.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong, but it is not exactly what I'm trying to do. I have multiple lines but within the same facet, and multiple facets. In that example with the iris dataset, you have one line per facet, whereas I have many.

Comment: This is why I asked for a sample of the original data set. The iris example was an attempt to help while waiting for the sample....